# Nella frase "se c'è una cosa non sei è serio", serve necessariamente un "che" dopo la parola "cosa" o è omissibile?

Tags: grammar

Mi rendo conto che la frase potrebbe beneficiare di una virgola dopo il "sei", ma il punto della domanda è: è sbagliato omettere quel "che", o è una questione di preferenza?
Se riusciste a rispondere con dei riferimenti a regole grammaticali specifiche sarebbe ancora meglio, grazie a tutti

Comment: Sì, occorre necessariamente un "che" (ed una virgola): "se c'è una cosa *che* non sei, è serio". Senza "che" la frase non ha senso, anche se probabilmente l'iterlocutore capirà comunque cosa intendessi dire, se è madrelingua.

Comment: Concordo con @secan e aggiungo che, sebbene io sia il primo a chiedere (e dare, quando posso) fonti e riferimenti precisi, qui è difficile farlo. È difficile che una grammatica dica come _non_ si dice (a meno che non parli di un errore ricorrente).

Comment: Omettere i pronomi relativi in quel modo è una cosa tipica dell'inglese. Dal mio punto di vista, non è strano che non si possa fare in italiano, è strano che si possa fare in inglese (anche confrontandolo con altre lingue).

Comment: Non ho un riferimento ad una regola grammaticale precisa, ma dal mio punto di vista il pronome relativo è necessario perché all'interno della frase si cambia soggetto. Il soggetto di `c'è` è `una cosa`, mentre il soggetto di `sei`è, ovviamente, `tu`. Il `che` sposta la  `cosa` da soggetto a complemento oggetto, ed è quindi indispensabile.

Comment: Grazie mille a tutti per le risposte. Come ho detto già alle persone che si sono subite questa frase, posso accettare di essere nel torto, ma a livello implicito non riesco a capire perché, tant'è che a me la frase continua a non suonare sbagliata. Può anche essere dovuto al fatto che vivo all'estero da un paio d'anni, e quindi la mia fluidità nel parlare italiano ne stia risentendo un po'.

Comment: @eager_to_learn, *se basterebbe che una frase suona giusta, anche questa lo sarebbe* (no, non è vero;mi sanguinavano gli occhi e le orecchie mentre la scrivevo, ma era per rendere l'idea XP). Comunque puoi fare riferimento a queste fonti: [treccani.it](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/proposizioni-oggettive_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/) e [scuola.zanichelli.it](https://aulalingue.scuola.zanichelli.it/benvenuti/2014/06/26/la-frase-complessa-le-proposizioni-oggettive-prima-parte/).[continua...]

Comment: [...]  In particolare, al secondo link si legge "*In alcuni casi possiamo avere l’omissione del che: penso (che) sia partito; dicono (che) abbia paura. **L’omissione del che è possibile solo quando il verbo della subordinata è al congiuntivo ed è utile per evitare la ripetizione a breve distanza di due che**, per esempio: ci sembra (che) sia opportuno che…*"

Answer (score 1):

Credo che "che" sia necessario. E io aggiungerei anche le virgolette attorno a "serio".

«Se c'è una cosa che non sei, è "serio"!»